# Dropbox SDK for iOS: How to determine which version you are using?

Tags: objective-c, ios, api, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using the Dropbox SDK but I installed it in my iOS app a long time ago. What is the best way to determine the SDK's version? I can't seem to find it in any of the header files.

Answer (score 2):

The SDK version is declared in kDBSDKVersion in DBSession.

Comment: NSLog(@"SDK Version %@",kDBSDKVersion);